# How can I run my rails "whenever"/cron tasks on OpenShift?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cron, openshift, whenever

When generating tasks via the **whenever** gem, the resulting line in **cron** format looks something like this:

```
0 13 30 * * /bin/bash -l -c 'cd $OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR && bin/rails runner -e production "puts \"test\""'
```

Now, when I SSH into the OpenShift app and try to execute that bash command for testing purposes, I get an error:

```
# /bin/bash -l -c 'cd $OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR && bin/rails runner -e production'
/opt/rh/ruby200/root/usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:53:in `require': cannot load such file -- bundler/setup (LoadError)
        from /opt/rh/ruby200/root/usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:53:in `require'
        from /var/lib/openshift/$APP_ID/app-root/runtime/repo/config/boot.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
        from /opt/rh/ruby200/root/usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:53:in `require'
        from /opt/rh/ruby200/root/usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:53:in `require'
        from bin/rails:9:in `<main>'
```

How can I ensure the `bin/rails runner` command to actually execute correcty?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
/bin/bash -l -c 'cd $OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR && bundle exec bin/rails runner -e production'
```

So that it will use your bundled gems when running the commands.